# SQL/Vertica - grouping multi-attribute combinations

Tags: sql, group-by, vertica

I have the following type of dataset:

```
user_id   country1  city1      country2  city2
1         usa       new york   france    paris 
2         usa       dallas     japan     tokyo 
3         india     mumbai     italy     rome 
4         france    paris      usa       new york 
5         brazil    sao paulo  russia    moscow
```

I want to group the combinations of `country1`, `city1`, `country2` and `city2` where the order (is something `country1` or `country2`) should not matter. Usually, I would try:

```
SELECT   country1 
       , city1
       , country2
       , city2 
       , COUNT(*) 
FROM dataset
GROUP BY country1 
       , city1
       , country2
       , city2
```

However, this code snippet considers the rows with `user_id=1` and `user_id=4` as two separate cases where I would like them to be considered as equivalent.

Anyone who knows how to coop with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you approach this type of problem using `least()` and `greatest()`, but you have two columns, instead of one.  So, let's do it by comparing cities.  I am guessing that `city` is more unique than `country`:

```
select (case when city1 < city2 then country1 else country2 end) as country1,
       (case when city1 < city2 then city1 else city2 end) as city1,
       (case when city1 < city2 then country2 else country1 end) as country2,
       (case when city1 < city2 then city2 else city1 end) as city2,
       count(*)
from dataset
group by (case when city1 < city2 then country1 else country2 end),
       (case when city1 < city2 then city1 else city2 end),
       (case when city1 < city2 then country2 else country1 end),
       (case when city1 < city2 then city2 else city1 end)
```